# Class not found error when running report on Grails-Jasper on Tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, grails, jasper-reports, jasper-plugin

I am using Jasper plugin in my Grails project. The application works well when running within NetBeans. But after deploying to Tomcat everything except reports works well. When I try to run a report (jasper) the hell breaks out. It gives "Class not found error.

```
2014-01-29 09:47:43,280 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - ClassNotFoundException occurred when processing request: [GET] /Ensign/jasper/index
org.joda.time.ReadableInstant. 
Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.ReadableInstant
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:157)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForName(JRClassLoader.java:115)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.functions.FunctionsBundle.addFunctionClass(FunctionsBundle.java:84)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.functions.FunctionsBundle.<init>(FunctionsBundle.java:54)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.functions.FunctionsRegistryFactory.createRegistry(FunctionsRegistryFactory.java:76)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.instantiateRegistry(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:239)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.loadRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:214)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.loadRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:162)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getRegistries(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:133)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:105)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.<clinit>(JRStyledTextParser.java:83)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:121)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:88)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:103)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:61)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:179)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:81)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:407)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:824)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
```

The versions I am using are 
Grails 2.2.4
Jasper plugin 1.7.0
Tomcat 7.0.34

Has anyone come across this issue? Any help or direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your BuildConfig.groovy?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the server you are missing the Joda Time library.

Download the [joda-time.jar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/joda-time/files/joda-time/) file and put it in the $TOMCAT_HOME/lib/ directory. Then restart your Tomcat and the error should be gone.